# Ubuntu server 14.04 CLI visual details

Tags: 14.04, command-line, server, graphics, xorg

Basically I am trying to find out everything that there is to find out about the visual details of CLI of Ubuntu Server 14.04. Before using Ubuntu Server 14.04, I used Ubuntu Server 10.04. When I switched, I noticed that the new CLI had better text, the text got smaller and there was some difference. I want to know what has changed. I want to know if Ubuntu Server 14.04 uses better graphic card driver. I want to know all the details regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called "Kernel Mode Setting" or KMS or the kernel frame buffer

> Kernel mode-setting (KMS) means that the kernel is responsible for setting up and changing the display mode: resolution, frequencies and color depth. Kernel modesetting and memory management describes some aspects of KMS along with Fedora specific information. KMS as a Linux feature was introduced in 2.6.29.

The Debian documentation is here -

https://wiki.debian.org/KernelModesetting

Additional documentation -

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_mode_setting

http://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/DrmModesetting/

http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/KernelModeSetting/

Comment: Thanks. So this means that there is no involvement of X11/Xorg in it.

Comment: Not with a console.